# Proof using the Bolzano-Cauchy Theorem

Tags: solution-verification, continuity

Consider $f$ and $g$ two functions with domain $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'$, the first derivative of $f$, continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $a$ and $b$ be two real numbers so that

- $b > a$
- $g(a) = b$
- $(g \circ g)(a) = a$

We know that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f'(x) \times [(g \circ g)(x) - g(x)]+f(x) > (f \circ g)(x)$.

Show that there is at least one tangent line to the graph of $f$ whose slope is $\frac{AROC_f,[a,b]}{AROC_g,[a,b]}$.

I thought using the Bolzano-Cauchy Theorem was the way to go and I would be able to prove this fact in $]a,b[$, taking the advantage of the fact that $f'$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, therefore being also necessarily continuous in $[a,b]$.

Having said this, I tried to prove that $\exists c \in ]a,b[: f'(c) = \frac{AROC_f,[a,b]}{AROC_g,[a,b]}$ and for that I wanted to prove $\frac{AROC_f,[a,b]}{AROC_g,[a,b]}$ to be an intermediate value between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$. I failed, but I believe I am pretty close and I am doing a mistake I am unable to find.

Here we go. Given that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f'(x) \times [(g \circ g)(x) - g(x)]+f(x) > (f \circ g)(x)$, we should have

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f'(x) \times [(g \circ g)(x) - g(x)]+f(x) > (f \circ g)(x) 
 \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f'(x) > \frac{(f \circ g)(x) - f(x)}{(g \circ g)(x) - g(x)}$.

So for $f'(a)$ I got

$f'(a) > \frac{(f \circ g)(a) - f(a)}{(g \circ g)(a) - g(a)} \Leftrightarrow f'(a) > \frac{f(g(a)) - f(a)}{g(g(a)) - g(a)} \Leftrightarrow f'(a) > \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)} \Leftrightarrow f'(a) > \frac{(f(b) - f(a))/(b-a)}{(g(b) - g(a))/(b-a)} \Leftrightarrow f'(a) > \frac{AROC_f,[a,b]}{AROC_g,[a,b]}$

and for $f'(b)$ I got

$f'(b) > \frac{(f \circ g)(b) - f(b)}{(g \circ g)(b) - g(b)} \Leftrightarrow f'(b) > \frac{f(g(b)) - f(b)}{g(g(b)) - g(b)} \Leftrightarrow f'(b) > \frac{f(g(g(a))) - f(b)}{g(g(g(a))) - g(b)} \Leftrightarrow f'(b) > \frac{f((g \circ g)(a)) - f(b)}{g((g \circ g)(a)) - g(b)} \Leftrightarrow f'(b) > \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{g(a) - g(b)} \Leftrightarrow f'(b) > \frac{(f(a) - f(b))/(b-a)}{(g(a) - g(b))/(b-a)} \Leftrightarrow f'(b) > \frac{-(f(b) - f(a))/(b-a)}{-(g(b) - g(a))/(b-a)} \Leftrightarrow f'(b) > \frac{-AROC_f,[a,b]}{-AROC_g,[a,b]} \Leftrightarrow f'(b) > \frac{AROC_f,[a,b]}{AROC_g,[a,b]}$

Having therefore both $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ higher than $\frac{AROC_f,[a,b]}{AROC_g,[a,b]}$, and I am unable to prove my point.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And the meaning of AROC is?

Comment: @FShrike Average Rate of Change